# How to combine various estpost sets in esttab

Tags: stata

Consider the following code snippet:

```
*Here I'm storing t-test as ttests
eststo ttests: estpost ttest Gender Black White, by(treated)

*Here this is the summary of all variable + 
eststo summstats: estpost summarize Gender Black White
eststo treated: estpost summarize Gender Black White if treated==1
eststo non_treated: estpost summarize  Gender Black White if treated==0

*table 1: Descriptive data
esttab summstats treated non_treated ttests using "${pathtable}\table_1.tex", label ///
replace main(mean %6.2f) aux(sd) mtitle("Total Sample" "Participants" "Non-Participants" ///
"p-value") title(Descriptive Table\label{tab1})
```

This uses the *community-contributed* command `esttab` to produce a table with means and standard deviations for `summstats`, `treated`, and `non_treated`.

However, in the last column I only get significance stars.

How can I display the actual p-value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces the desired output:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

eststo ttests: estpost ttest price mpg trunk, by(foreign)

eststo summstats: estpost summarize price mpg trunk
eststo treated: estpost summarize price mpg trunk if foreign==1
eststo non_treated: estpost summarize price mpg trunk if foreign==0

esttab summstats             ///
       treated               ///
       non_treated           ///
       ttests,               ///
       cell(p(fmt(%6.3f)) &  ///
       mean(fmt(%6.2f))      ///
       sd(fmt(%6.3f) par))   ///
       label replace         ///
       mtitle("Total"        ///
              "Foreign"      ///
              "Domestic"     ///
              "p-value")     ///
       title(Descriptive     ///
             Table)          ///
       collabels(none)
```

```
 Descriptive Table
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              (1)          (2)          (3)          (4)
                            Total      Foreign     Domestic      p-value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                     6165.26      6384.68      6072.42       0.680 
                       (2949.496)   (2621.915)   (3097.104)             
Mileage (mpg)               21.30        24.77        19.83       0.001 
                          (5.786)      (6.611)      (4.743)             
Trunk space (.. ft.)        13.76        11.41        14.75       0.002 
                          (4.277)      (3.217)      (4.306)             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   74           22           52           74
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry was caught up with work and couldn't provide the example data... Thank you!